# Compound mysql Select After outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have a table A with columns (a, b) and a table B with columns (b, c). I want to do the following:

```
STEP 1: do a   A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.b = B.b
STEP 2: convert all c = NULL in the Joined table to c = <default_value>
STEP 3: SUM(A.a * B.c) over the table I get after STEP 2
```

Is there a quick way to do this in one compound statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the three steps in one query, first `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and use `IFNULL` to set the `NULL` values to a default value, then use `SUM`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(A.a + IFNULL(B.c, <default_value>))
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.b = B.b;
```

SQL Fiddle Demo:

- [**STEP 1, STEP 2**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f322/2).
- [**STEP 3**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f322/4).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  sum(A.a + IFNULL(B.c, some_default)) as some_sum
FROM
  A
  LEFT JOIN B
    ON
      B.b = A.b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select sum(A.a * (case when B.c = null then <default> else B.c end)) as joined_sum
 from A left outer join B on (A.b = B.b);
```